# Where do I find personal messages that someone has sent me by using @username?

Tags: discussion, support

@Verbeia suggested that I might respond to a question by someone interested in finance, and I would like to do so, but I only saw her message by accident when I was poking around in my user area, and now I can't find it even thought I saw it only one hour ago.  I've looked everywere in my user area, and still can't find it again. This seems like a SE problem.  I never got anything like "you've got mail," and I saw the question only because I was rummaging around. Furthermore, I don't know how to send Verbeia a message to thank her and find the question again.

This is probably an inexperienced user issue, but it seems like SE should have told me about her message.

Ok, I found Verbeia's message again, by going to the little "StackExchange" button at the upper left of the web page.  I still would like to know how to send someone else a message of some kind.  Do you do it by making an @username comment anywhere in MMA SE?

Comment: If you happen to miss a notification from someone (i.e., you accidentally dismissed from the inbox), you can find it in the [responses tab on your user profile](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/2308/george-wolfe?tab=responses) (deleted comments won't show up)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways:

1. Include their name with an @ in front in a comment under a comment or post that they have posted.
2. If they have been in the chat room lately, you can use the same @ technique to "ping" them in chat.

Both kinds of messages will appear in the inbox that can be accessed in that little StackExchange menu at the top of the screen. You will get a little red circle with a number to show how many new messages you have.

As an aside, the reason I saw this post so quickly is probably not the @Verbeia in the title and text, but rather, because moderators get inbox notifications whenever someone posts to meta.

Comment: @Verbeia I just used the @ symbol to pink Daniel Lichtblau and ruebenko in an answer that I posted.  Daniel had posted a comment in another thread and, as far as I know, ruebenko hasn't even seen the post. Can I expect them to see the ping? The message is here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11731/

Comment: @MarkMcClure The @ symbol will never work in the body  of an answer or a question. So no, neither of them will get a ping. I've seen people write that way though — they're either mistaken about it or it's due to a habit from using twitter and Facebook.